# AngularJS Error: document.querySelector(...).innerText is undefined

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic App and have a jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zox8yh55/4/), which outputs the following errors:

in Firefox:
`Error: document.querySelector(...).innerText is undefined`

and in Google Chrome:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`

In Chrome I can see the created contents. In Firefox no content. If I install the application on iOS and Android, I also see no content which is parsed from JSON. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In which scenario does it happen? Otherwise everything is fine when I test it

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that from JSON parsed content (ie HTML component like buttons) simply can be changed just in the JSON file. I want to remove/customize or add new components only from and in the JSON file. That ist my goal.

Comment: It may be of course that a different function or dependency causes this error in my app. I don't have a single function on my app. Therefore, I can not yet say exactly in which scenario happened this.

Comment: The only vector I see, is that "#loadhere" somehow does not always exist, and you try to append something to a `null` reference.

Comment: What would be your concrete proposal for a solution?

Comment: I'd says you should always check for the existence of the element with id "loadhere" and handle your own scenario for errors

Comment: what syntax is correct (see the code)? Is it correct that `$templateCache.get("tpl").trim()` `"tpl"` is written without `#` or? and `angular.element(document.querySelector("#loadhere"))` `"loadhere"` with `#`?